# current Focus Value of camera in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera, windows-phone, autofocus

I am developing a simple windows phone application. I want to get the current focus value of the camera. Any body help me if the default API gives me this type of information? If yes, then how i can get this value. If there is no support for that in default API then how i can get this value.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by focus value?

Comment: By focus value i mean that when camera makes focus on some object, so that object is as clear as it can get.